How to get code from msal browser as I'm geting undefined microsoft graph api
I'm trying to access code to send it in backend to get access token and refresh token of a Microsoft account using Microsoft graph API and msal browser. This is my code
const authorizeEmail = async (idToken: string | undefined) => {
if (!idToken) {
  return;
}
const token = await getIdTokenClaims();
await axios.post(
  `${process.env.BASE_URL}/email/authorize/`,
  {
    code: idToken,
    deal_id: 22,
  },
  {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}`,
    },
  }
);
};


const loginAndGetAuthorizationCode = async () => {
const loginRequest = {
  scopes: ["User.Read", "Mail.Read", "offline_access"]
};

try {
  const loginResponse = await msalInstance.loginPopup(loginRequest);
  await authorizeEmail(loginResponse.code); // this is coming undefined

  return loginResponse.code;
} catch (error) {
  console.error("Login failed: ", error);
}
};


Could you confirm whether your requirement is to acquire authorization code in order to get access token for Microsoft Graph using authorization code flow?

Yes, I need with authorization code to get access and refresh token to get emails

Hi @WebDev Any update?

The issue is that the loginResponse in MSAL.js doesn’t return an authorization code in client-side apps like React. Instead, it provides the idToken and accessToken directly.
I registered one Azure AD application and added same API permissions as below:

In Authentication tab, I added redirect URI as http://localhost:3000 in Single-page application platform and enabled public client flow like this:

In my case, I used below code files and got tokens and emails of signed-in user successfully like this:
authConfig.js:
// src/authConfig.js
export const msalConfig = {
    auth: {
      clientId: "appId", // Application (client) ID
      authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId", // Directory (tenant) ID
      redirectUri: "http://localhost:3000", // Your redirect URI
    },
  };
  
  export const loginRequest = {
    scopes: ["User.Read", "Mail.Read", "offline_access"], // Adjust scopes as needed
  };

App.js:
// src/App.js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { msalConfig, loginRequest } from "./authConfig";
import { PublicClientApplication } from "@azure/msal-browser";
import axios from "axios"; 

const msalInstance = new PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);

const App = () => {
  const [accessToken, setAccessToken] = useState("");
  const [idToken, setIdToken] = useState(""); 
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]); 
  const [userName, setUserName] = useState("");

  // Initialize MSAL on app load
  useEffect(() => {
    const initializeMSAL = async () => {
      try {
        await msalInstance.initialize(); 
        console.log("MSAL initialized successfully");
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("MSAL initialization failed: ", error);
      }
    };

    initializeMSAL();
  }, []);

  const loginAndGetToken = async () => {
    try {
      const loginResponse = await msalInstance.loginPopup(loginRequest);
      console.log("Login successful!", loginResponse);

      // Set the active account after successful login
      msalInstance.setActiveAccount(loginResponse.account);

      // Access tokens and ID token
      const newAccessToken = loginResponse.accessToken;
      const newIdToken = loginResponse.idToken; // Get the ID token

     
      setAccessToken(newAccessToken);
      setIdToken(newIdToken); 

      setUserName(loginResponse.account.name); 
      
      await callGraphAPI(newAccessToken);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Login failed: ", error);
      alert(`Login failed: ${error.message}`);
    }
  };

  const callGraphAPI = async (token) => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages", {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`, 
        },
      });
      console.log("Graph API Response:", response.data);
      setMessages(response.data.value); 
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Graph API call failed:", error);
    }
  };

  const logout = () => {
    msalInstance.logoutPopup(); 
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>MSAL Login</h1>
      {!accessToken ? ( 
        <button onClick={loginAndGetToken}>Login</button>
      ) : (
        <div>
          <h2>Logged in as: {userName}</h2> {/* Display user's name */}
          <button onClick={logout}>Logout</button>
        </div>
      )}
      {accessToken && (
        <div>
          <h2>Access Token:</h2>
          <p>{accessToken}</p>
        </div>
      )}
      {idToken && (
        <div>
          <h2>ID Token:</h2>
          <p>{idToken}</p>
        </div>
      )}
      {messages.length > 0 && (
        <div>
          <h2>Messages:</h2>
          <ul>
            {messages.map((message) => (
              <li key={message.id}>
                <strong>{message.subject}</strong> - {message.bodyPreview}
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;

Output:

